# How can I disable in LimeSurvey the Registration e-mail confirmation?

Tags: php, survey, limesurvey

How can I disable in LimeSurvey the "Registration" e-mail confirmation after an user insert his name, surname and e-mail address? What I want is the user starts the survey right away without need to confirm his email in order to start the survey.

OBS: Anonymized responses is set to 'NO'
I'm using LimeSurvey Version 2.00+ Build 130923.

Anyone can help me with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With 2.05 : you can replace default register system with a plugin. See https://github.com/Shnoulle/LS-replaceRegister for some example.

With 2.06 (next version), you have new events to do it more easily [beforeRegister](http://manual.limesurvey.org/BeforeRegister) can redirect to the survey with the good token.